Show Trashed Items in Laravel
I have many products in my categories and I can get all of the products based on the category successfully. But, when I tried to get the trashed Categories (I used soft delete both in the categories and products), it gave me an error

Call to a member function products() on null

I've tried to use a different function name, but the error still occurs.
Models
// CategoryModel
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id','id');
}

// ProductModel
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'category_id','id')->withTrashed();
}

Controllers
// IndexController
public function productByCategory($name)
{
    $categories = Categories::where('name', $name)->first();
    $productsCategories = $categories->products()->get(); // the error occurs here 
    return view('products-category', compact('productsCategories','categories'));
}

// CategoryController
public function trash()
{
    $categories = Categories::onlyTrashed()->paginate(10);
    return view("categories.trash", compact('categories'));
}

// ProductController
public function trash()
{
    $products = Product::onlyTrashed()->paginate(10);
    return view("products.trash", compact('products'));
}


For the error, the two trash() functions are not relevant. But it's good that you mentioned you're using soft delete. Errors like this and similar ones often arise from a lack of proper error handling. Always keep in mind that you might not get the expected result. For example, it's not guaranteed that a category with the name $name currently exists.

Suggestion: use Categories::with(['products'])->where('name', $name)->first(); to preload related products when querying the category... This reduces the number of database queries, improving performance (avoids N+1 query problem).

After some time, I figured it was because it's read as the same route address. The "trash" is considered as a "name" parameter by Laravel. I solved it by changing the route address

When querying the categories in productByCategory, include the trashed items as well. I assume that when deleting a category, you don't remove its associations with the products.
$category = Category::withTrashed()->where('name', $name)->first();

Of course, more logic can be added, but for now, the issue is caused by the trashed categories that are associated with the products. It is not mandatory to handle deleted categories, but the null check would be important for error handling.
public function productByCategory($name)
{
    // or without withTrashed() if the $name exists but the category has already been deleted, the result will still be null
    $category = Category::withTrashed()->where('name', $name)->first();

    // Handle case where category is not found
    if (is_null($category)) {
        abort(404, "Category not found: $name.");
    }

    // products by category
    $products = $category->products()->get();

    return view('products-category', compact('products', 'category'));
}

Always remember that a query may not necessarily return any results. Such cases should always be handled.
(Also, I was very confused by the incorrect use of naming conventions: for example, instead of using the singular form "category", you kept using the plural, which made the entire answer confusing at first. I have corrected these in my own response.)
Update
Based on the description in the comment, there should be a different return for trashed and non-trashed categories.
public function productByCategory($name)
{
    $category = Category::withTrashed()->where('name', $name)->first();

    // Handle case where category is not found
    if (is_null($category)) {
        abort(404, "Category not found: $name.");
    }

    $products = $category->products()->get();

    // Return different views based on whether the category is trashed or not
    // Trashed
    if ($category->trashed()) {
        return view('trashed-products-category', compact('products', 'category'));
    }

    // Non-trashed
    return view('products-category', compact('products', 'category'));
}


Or for better UX return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Category not found.');

Hi, what if I want to show the products by category and the trashed category in a different page?

With the provided productsByCategory function, you're querying a single category that matches the $name, and you will get all products associated with that category as a result. You can determine whether a category is trashed or not, and based on that, you can pass the result to two different Blade views. I've updated my response with this new branching logic.

Hi, it still gives me a not found error for the trashed category blade. FYI, I made the trashed category logic in a different controller called CategoryController. In IndexController, I want to display the non-trashed category (and the products), and in Category Controller I want to display the trashed category only

Hi. I'm afraid I don't understand your problem. My solution is definitely correct: for actual question; for Call to a member function products() on null. I'm not sure exactly where you're getting stuck. If you could create a new question and describe in detail what you're trying to achieve, I would be able to provide a specific answer to that new question. Feel free to open a new question if you encounter a problem that is different from the subject of the current question.

The answer to the current question is that the Category model ->first() function can return a null value, on which it cannot call the products() query. My answer perfectly highlights this.

Hi, I already posted a new question to explain in details for what I need here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79220194/show-products-based-on-category-and-the-trashed-category-in-the-different-blade. Thank you for your help!

You're having this error because in your productByCategory method, you're trying to access the products relationship of a category, but the
Categories::where('name', $name)->first() call may return null if there is no category with that name found.
To properly handle soft-deleted categories and avoid this error, you need to include soft-deleted records in your query using the withTrashed method when fetching the category. Here's the updated method below:
public function productByCategory($name)
{
    // Fetch the category, including soft-deleted ones
    $categories = Categories::withTrashed()->where('name', $name)->first();

    // Check if the category exists
    if (!$categories) {
        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Category not found.');
    }

    // Fetch products for the category
    $productsCategories = $categories->products()->get();

    return view('products-category', compact('productsCategories', 'categories'));
}

Also, you'll need to update your models, to ensure soft-deleted relationship works properly.
For the category model, add withTrashed to the products relationship to include soft-deleted products when retrieving categories.
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
}

for the product model, the category relationship already uses withTrashed() for categories, so it should work fine as it is
