Show Products Based on Category and the Trashed Category in the Different Blade Laravel
I have many products in my categories and I can get all of the products based on the non-trashed category successfully (I used soft delete both in the categories and products).
I also have a different page to display the trashed category (of course without the products) But, when I tried to get the trashed category, it gave me an error

Call to a member function products() on null

Here's the Code:
Models
// CategoryModel
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'category_id','id');
}

// ProductModel
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Categories::class, 'category_id','id')->withTrashed();
}

Controllers
//IndexController (Here I display all of the products based on non-trashed category for public access)
public function productByCategory($name)
{
    $categories = Categories::where('name', $name)->first();
    $productsCategories = $categories->products()->get(); // the error occurs here 
    return view('products-category', compact('productsCategories','categories'));
}

//CategoryController (Here I display all of the trashed categories, without the product, for admin access)
public function trash()
{
    $categories = Categories::onlyTrashed()->paginate(10);
    return view("categories.trash", compact('categories'));
}

//ProductController (Here I display all of the products for admin access)
public function trash()
{
    $products = Product::onlyTrashed()->paginate(10);
    return view("products.trash", compact('products'));
}

EDITED
The error shows when I try to view the trashed category in admin access, but I don't know why it occurs on IndexController. Also, there's no error in the trashed category function. I also could display all of the products based on category successfully
How can the trashed category be displayed for admin access without causing problems in the Index Controller? Thank you
EDITED 2
Complete Index Controller
public function index() //I use it in index page
{
    $brands = Brand::all();
    $categories = Categories::all();
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('index', compact('brands', 'categories', 'products'));
}

public function products() //to display all of the products in product menu, in index page
{
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('products', compact('products'));
}

public function productByCategory($name) //I use it to display products based on the category in the index page
{
    $categories = Categories::where('name', $name)->first();
    $productsCategories = $categories->products()->get();
    return view('products-category', compact('productsCategories','categories'));
}


While the naming is somewhat confusing (Categories instead of Category and productsCategories instead of something like productsOfCategory) the code is correct; for me no error occurs at the line you marked. The error simply means that $categories is empty; no record was found by that $name.
